# String to date conversion in Java exception

Tags: date, simpledateformat, date-conversion

I know my question is deprecated but i can't really solve my problem.

Well i'm trying to convert a String to Date, but i'm getting unappeasable date exception. Here is my code:

```
String issued = "Thu, 31 Mar 2015 08:21:47 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

            try {

                Date date = formatter2.parse(issued);

                Log.d("issued date", ""+date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Can any body tell me what is my problem !!

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any errors in your code. Are you sure it's getting thrown from the snippet you posted?

Comment: Yes sure, i dont understand why i'm getting this error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, well t's a partial solution!.

```
String issued = "Thu, 02 Apr 2015 12:10:02";
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

            try {

                Date date = formatter2.parse(issued);

                Log.d("issued date", ""+date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

1) I added , Locale.US
2) I removed time zone (GMT)

Good luck.

Comment: Adding/Setting the locale should be sufficient.